# Python time from a 6 digit number

Tags: python, time, np

I have a series of six digit numbers in this array:

```
a = np.array((121011,121020,121025,121030,121032,121037,121234))
```

How do I get a time from each of the six digit numbers? e.g.:

```
12:10:11
```

I wish to use the time for calculations.

Comment: Do you want the time as a string?

Comment: No, I wish the time to be numbers so that I can use them for calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you wanted to do calculations, you probably want `time` objects, not strings.
See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#time-objects).

```
for number in a:
    h = number // 10000
    m = (number // 100) - (h * 100)
    s = number % 100
    t = time(h,m,s)
    # then do whatever you want with t
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to strings, split and print out would work:

```
for number in a:
    str_number = str(number)
    print('{}:{}:{}'. format(str_number[:2], str_number[2:4], str_number[4:]))


12:10:11
12:10:20
12:10:25
12:10:30
12:10:32
12:10:37
12:12:34
```